# How do I center align 3 radio buttons?

Tags: android

```
<RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/q1_group"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight=".07"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="0dip"
    android:paddingLeft="0dip" >
```

I want to center these 3 radio buttons. How would I do so? I already tried setting `android:gravity="center"`, but it did not center the radio buttons.

```
    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/q1a3"
        android:layout_width="102dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="5" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/q1a1"
        android:layout_width="106dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="4" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/q1a2"
        android:layout_width="101dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="118dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="2" />
</RadioGroup>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap your `RadioGroup` with `RelativeLayout` and in `RadioGroup` set `android:layout_centerVertical="true"` and `android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"` attributes.

Here's how it would be like,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/q1_group"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/q1a3"
        android:layout_width="102dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="5" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/q1a1"
        android:layout_width="106dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="4" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/q1a2"
        android:layout_width="101dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="2"/>

</RadioGroup>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use android:gravity="center" for parent layout.I defined android:gravity="center" in parent layout (RelativeLayout)

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.actionbarexample.MainActivity"
    android:gravity="center" >

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/q1_group"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight=".07"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingBottom="0dip"
        android:paddingLeft="0dip" >

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/q1a3"
            android:layout_width="102dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="5" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/q1a1"
            android:layout_width="106dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="4" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/q1a2"
            android:layout_width="101dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="118dp"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="2" />
    </RadioGroup>

</RelativeLayout>
```

- android:gravity="center" is used when you want content inside layout is centred .

Answer (score 0):

RadioGroup is the child class of LinearLayout, so you can use properties of linear layout to set radio buttons to center.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RadioGroup.html

And it also seems that you have given android:layout_height="wrap_content"
which doesn't solve your problem for vertically center radio buttons.
But for for horizontal center you have to use another layout for the radio group implementation as in linear layout android:gravity="center" wont work.