# Horizontally Center Radio Buttons In Div

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to horizontally center a set of three radio buttons but am not having successs.

Here's the code I have:

**HTML**

```
<div class="section-wrap section-flavors">
        <input id="r11" name="radio3" type="radio" value="radio_btn"  class="flavors-radio">
   <label for="r11"><span></span>Don't Want</label>
        <input id="r12" name="radio3" type="radio" value="radio_btn" class="flavors-radio">
   <label for="r12"><span></span>Don't Care</label>
        <input id="r13" name="radio3" type="radio" value="radio_btn" checked class="flavors-radio">
   <label for="r13"><span></span>Want</label>
 </div>
```

Here's the CSS I have for it:

**CSS**

```
.content .section-wrap {
  background: #f1f8e9;
  padding: 30px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

I've tried adding text-align center and display: inline-block but to no avail.

I've also checked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28945581/how-do-i-center-align-3-radio-buttons) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28945581/how-do-i-center-align-3-radio-buttons) but have not been able to apply their answers to my situation.  Thanks.

Comment: "*I've tried adding `text-align center` and `display: inline-block`*" - what elements, or selectors, you add these rules to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this:

```
.section-wrap{
    text-align:center;
}
```

Here is an embedded demo:

```css
.section-wrap {
  background: #f1f8e9;
  padding: 30px;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<div class="section-wrap section-flavors">
        <input id="r11" name="radio3" type="radio" value="radio_btn"  class="flavors-radio">
   <label for="r11"><span></span>Don't Want</label>
        <input id="r12" name="radio3" type="radio" value="radio_btn" class="flavors-radio">
   <label for="r12"><span></span>Don't Care</label>
        <input id="r13" name="radio3" type="radio" value="radio_btn" checked class="flavors-radio">
   <label for="r13"><span></span>Want</label>
 </div>
```

[Here is the **JSFiddle** demo](https://jsfiddle.net/dfL0pqmw/)

Comment: demo link broken

Comment: @StackOverflowUser Updated the link and also added an embedded demo